# How do I use indexOf() case insensitively?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list of strings:

```
List<string> fnColArr = new List<string>();
fnColArr={"Punctuation,period,Space,and,yes"};
```

I am using the `IndexOf` property for `List` to find the string in the current list:

```
int arrayval = fnColArr.IndexOf("punctuation");
```

Now the value of `arrayval` is -1, because the string is not present in the list. But here the only difference is the lower case.

I want to also find the string `punctuation`, regardless of its case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can Use Overloaded Method

```
IndexOf("punctuation", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Eg.

```
List<string> fnColArr = new List<string>() 
{ "Punctuation", "period", "Space", "and", "yes" };

            foreach (string item in fnColArr)
            {
                if (item.IndexOf("puNctuation", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("match");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Why is this technique giving me syntax errors, "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringComparer to 'Int'

Comment: @0xG this answer uses `StringComparison` not `StringComparer`, so make sure you're using that instead, because that is probably why you had that error

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could also use a lambda function
`fnColArr.FindIndex(x => x.ToLower().Equals("punctuation"));`

Comment: thanks for your reply , but no need of convert fully lowercase to the string

Comment: Just change the equals.   fnColArr.FindIndex(x => x.Equals("punctuation",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

Comment: That is not a great idea as it creates `fnColArr.Length` redundant allocations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this.

```
List<string> fnColArr = new List<string> {"Punctuation","period","Space","and","yes"};
int arrayval = fnColArr.IndexOf("punctuation",StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: yes, it is not a problem it is came from database , am just showing here

Answer (score 0):

String now has a `StringComparison` parameter that is second last.

`string.IndexOf(string, StringComparison) is >=0 | -1`

```
    public string IgnoreCaseTrimStart(string value, string trim)
    {
        int Position = 0;
        char[] Glyphics = trim.ToCharArray ( );
        foreach ( char Glyph in Glyphics )
        {
            if (value.IndexOf( Glyph, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) == Position )
            {
                Position++;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return value.Substring(Position, value.Length - Position).Trim();
    }
```

Code for Console AutoComplete.